# Recover space from persistent storage by Tails OS?

Tags: linux, live-usb, disk-encryption, tails-os

I installed Tails in a USB stick and enabled persistent storage. The USB had 16GB of storage. Now I formatted the USB without freeing up the persistent storage and lost 10GB of space. I remember the passphrase I set while installing. Is there a way to recover that space?

https://tails.boum.org/install/win/usb/index.en.html

I followed step 5/5 at the bottom of the page here. It was a dumb thing to do I know.

Comment: If anybody needs, I actually solved it by reinstalling Tails on it and that free-uped the space blocked by persistent storage.